# Jquery - Get previous value row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have dynamic simple table like: 
 [image]

I try to get previous value cell when i click edit button.

Example: when i click first edit button that will alert('a1')
when i click second edit button that will alert('a2')

i try with

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parents('tr').prev().children().eq(1).text());
});
```

it's working well with first edit button because previous row that has one row.
And it't not working with second edit button.
How can i do it (by dynamic previous row) **http://jsfiddle.net/bWjbj/**

ps: i'm working with next row with

```
alert($(this).parents('tr').nextAll(':eq(' + ($(this).parent().siblings().eq(0).attr("rowspan")-1) + ')').children().eq(1).text());
```

Comment: So, clicking the Edit button should return the table cell contents for the previous row's second column?

Comment: simple like that: click edit1 -> show "a1". click edit2 -> show "a2"

Comment: Yes, you already said that, however I'm trying to confirm that the pattern I asked about is what you want. Otherwise I see no correlation between the edit buttons and the values you want.

Comment: sorry, maybe it's delete button :). But it's simple example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/XGdkD/

The problem is that for the second Edit button, the previous table row isn't the row you want -- you want the row two more before that, because that's where the rowspans begin.

Or, to be general: you want *the table row belonging to the previous Edit button.* In the case of the first edit button, though, you just want the previous row.

So, in code:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    var idx = $('.edit').index(this); // which Edit button is this?
    if (idx > 0) { // first button
        var $tr = $('.edit').eq(idx-1).closest('tr'); // previous row
    } else { // not first button
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'); // previous Edit button's row
    }
    var $td = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)'); // second <td> of the row
    alert($td.text());
});
```

Compact version of the same code:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    var idx = $('.edit').index(this),
        $tr = (idx) ? $('.edit').eq(idx-1).closest('tr') : $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr'),
        $td = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)');
    alert($td.text());
});
```

Comment: it's working well. Can you explain your code. I try it and all case, always idx > 0. And find('td:nth-child(2)') what it's doing. thanks

Comment: `idx==0` for the first `Edit` button only. http://api.jquery.com will explain what the various methods and selectors actually do.